# Remove stylesheet selectively in Drupal for page

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming, drupal-zen

I am trying to make different layout for the front page. In that process I declared new stylesheet called "front-page.css" and page--front.tpl.php. I am using a Zen subtheme which loads responsive-sidebar.css. I want to remove "responsive-sidebar.css" and load "front-page.css". 
The reason I am doing it because the number of grind columns in the later stylesheet is different that former.

I don't want to use Panels module. I am using Drupal 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Drupal 7 way is to use [`hook_css_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_css_alter/7):

```
function MYMODULE_css_alter(&$css) {
  // Remove defaults.css file. The path will probably change for your theme obviously.
  unset($css[drupal_get_path('theme', 'MYTHEME') . '/css/responsive-sidebar.css']);
}
```

That hook can be implemented in either a module or a theme.

Answer (score 2):

Inside your theme's `template.php` file and inside the [template_preprocess_page($vars)](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/7), find the CSS file you want to remove inside `$vars['stylesheets']` and use PHP's `unset` function to remove it from the `$vars['stylesheets']` array.

Comment: This would work in Drupal 6 but stylesheets key is not present in $vars array in Drupal 7. D7 has changed the way to do it!

Answer (score 0):

I just found better way to do this. It is bit hacky, but allows to unset css at almost any place:

```
$css = &drupal_static('drupal_add_css', array());
unset($css['some_css_path']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Drupal 8 way. Maybe it works in Drupal 7.  For remove stylesheet on a certain/specific page you need:

```
function MYTHEME_css_alter(&$css) {

// Get me path:
  $current_path = \Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath();
  $result = \Drupal::service('path.alias_manager')->getAliasByPath($current_path);

    if ($result == 'your/path' ){
      unset($css[drupal_get_path('theme', 'THEMENAME') . '/css/style.css']);
    }
}
```

It works for me in D8 and can put it in .theme or .module. You need delete all caches (or module caches) necessarily.